# Periodically refresh placeholder and canvas tag in Django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, chart.js

I have a template that, among other things, displays a current market price through a placeholder, i.e., `{{ market.current_price }}`, and an accompanying price graph using [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/), rendered in the template in a canvas tag, `<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>`.

**My question**: since the market price changes as different users engage with the underlying market, **is there a straightforward way to periodically (say, every 10 seconds) refresh the placeholder and chart in the template**, to make sure each user is looking at the most recent price/graph?

I'm trying to avoid having to refresh the entire page, if at all possible.

If it makes any difference, the chart is rendered through Ajax, as follows:

```
{% block jquery %}
            var endpoint = "{% url 'chart_data' market.id %}"
            var defaultData = []
            var labels = []
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: endpoint,
                success: function(data){
                    defaultData = data.prices
                    price_array_length = defaultData.length + 1
                    labels = data.price_dates
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets : [{
                                label: 'Market price',
                                data: defaultData,
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 2
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        suggestedMin: 0,
                                        suggestedMax: 1
                                    }
                                }]
                            },
                            animation: {
                                duration: 500 // general animation time
                            },
                            hover: {
                                animationDuration: 500 // duration of animations when hovering an item
                            },
                            responsiveAnimationDuration: 500 // animation duration after a resize
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
{% endblock %}
```

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I haven't used ChartJS too much but if you want to update a graph I believe you have to have a function that takes in the chart and calls `chart.update()`. I would imagine you could `setInterval()` for whatever time you want that would request the new data and call `chart.update()` after you do what you need to with the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution: Building on @MichaelCacciano's suggestion, I wrapped the JQuery in a function (`refresh_graph`), and also dropped the Django placeholder in favour of a tag (`currentPrice`), both of which now update every second, as follows:

```
<script>
    function refresh_graph() {
        {% block jquery %}
            var endpoint = "{% url 'chart_data' market.id %}"
            var defaultData = []
            var labels = []
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: endpoint,
                success: function(data){
                    defaultData = data.prices
                    price_array_length = defaultData.length + 1
                    labels = data.price_dates
                    var current = defaultData[defaultData.length-1];
                    document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = current;
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets : [{
                                label: 'Market price',
                                data: defaultData,
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 2
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        suggestedMin: 0,
                                        suggestedMax: 1
                                    }
                                }]
                            },
                            animation: {
                                duration: 0 // general animation time
                            },
                            hover: {
                                animationDuration: 0 // duration of animations when hovering an item
                            },
                            responsiveAnimationDuration: 500 // animation duration after a resize
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        setTimeout(refresh_graph, 1000);
        }
        setTimeout(refresh_graph, 0);
    {% endblock %}
</script>
```